# Best way to query and show database results in succession?

Tags: php, database

This question is more of a brainstorming/optimization question. I am still new to website development and I am curious as to the most efficient way to do database querying.

There is a filter menu being displayed that users can select as filter parameters for there results. I want users to be able to change the parameters on the fly (which they can) and have it requery the database as such.

I can just resubmit the form everytime in GET and requery the database and display each time, but I was wondering if there is a more effective way to do this.

An example filter can be seen here: http://lolteamrecruiter.com/find/player.php

Comment: It's too early for you to optimize anything. First learn something that at least work and won't be hacked by script kiddies

Comment: thank you for your wonderful insight into this inquiry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an answer to your question you need to look into jQuery or plain JavaScript. Its faster to use jQuery AJAX and get the return data, parse it and display your results than to think to much into a task that will land you back in JavaScripts lap.

End result of this is use AJAX for "on the fly" data returns and "no-reload" screen manipulation.

Actual database optimization is not done on the query side as much as on the database side.

Comment: I meant optimization for client side, not actual database optimizing. I would assume any database worth its weight in data would be internally optimized. As for your answer, this is what I was looking for, thank you for the suggestion. Accepted.